# plot from sankeyNetwork in networkD3 does not show output neither generates any warning/error in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I want to generate a Sankey plot to visualize movements to different areas using `sankeyNetwork()` from the package [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) in [r](/questions/tagged/r). I tried to mimic some examples as perfectly as possible. But when I run the function `sankeyNetwork`, no output is generated. On top of that, R doesn't show any warnings, erros et cetera. Therefore, I can't really check whether I made mistakes (obviously, because no plot is generated) and how to fix them. I provided a sample df and the code below.

```
library(networkD3)

nodes <- data.frame(area = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
                            "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n")) 

links2 <- data.frame(source = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
                                 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13), 
                     target = c(2, 8, 10, 11, 13, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 0, 4, 9, 10, 12, 13, 0, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 7, 10, 12, 
                     0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 9, 10, 13, 10, 12, 13, 0, 11, 12, 13, 0, 14, 0, 0), 
                     value  = c(14, 4, 6, 23, 3, 6, 36, 3, 4, 4, 3, 12, 3, 24, 3, 6, 19, 3, 9, 3, 6, 3, 11, 9, 3, 22, 3, 3, 10, 3, 4, 
                                3, 3, 9, 12, 5, 16, 13, 3, 10, 3, 4, 9, 7, 4, 4, 77, 4, 6, 6, 27, 3, 3, 3))

sankeyNetwork(Links = links2, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "source", Target = "target",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "area",
              fontSize= 12, nodeWidth = 30)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You refer to 15 unique nodes in your `links2` data frame, but you only have 14 unique nodes in your `nodes` data frame.

```
length(unique(c(links2$source, links2$target)))
# [1] 15
length(nodes$area)
# [1] 14
```

If you add another node, it will work...

```
library(networkD3)

nodes <- data.frame(area = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
                             "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o")) 

links2 <- data.frame(source = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
                                5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 13, 13), 
                     target = c(2, 8, 10, 11, 13, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 0, 4, 9, 10, 12, 13, 0, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 7, 10, 12, 
                                0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 9, 10, 13, 10, 12, 13, 0, 11, 12, 13, 0, 14, 0, 0), 
                     value  = c(14, 4, 6, 23, 3, 6, 36, 3, 4, 4, 3, 12, 3, 24, 3, 6, 19, 3, 9, 3, 6, 3, 11, 9, 3, 22, 3, 3, 10, 3, 4, 
                                3, 3, 9, 12, 5, 16, 13, 3, 10, 3, 4, 9, 7, 4, 4, 77, 4, 6, 6, 27, 3, 3, 3))

sankeyNetwork(Links = links2, Nodes = nodes,
              Source = "source", Target = "target",
              Value = "value", NodeID = "area",
              fontSize= 12, nodeWidth = 30)
```

[image]